# Why JavaFX SceneBuilder forced me to add extra code for GridPane

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I'm learning JavaFX and tried SceneBuilder. But I'm wonder why ScreenBuilder manage `Rows` and `Columns` by adding following code.

```
<columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints />
   </columnConstraints>
   <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints />
   </rowConstraints>
```

I know it is just one column and one row. But in the coding, I didn't add such code and `GridPane` works fine, and even Oracle offical examples are also managing `GridPane` without creating `rows` and `columns` externally and using just `rowIndex`, `columnIndex`.

Then why SceneBuilder adding such lines? 
is there any alternative to SceneBuilder in JavaFx?

Comment: Those tags are simply the parent tags for where column and row definitions will go if they are anything other than the default properties

Answer (score 0):

The `<columnConstraints></columnConstraints>` are where the definitions for each row and column go. The line `<ColumnConstraints />` is simply a plain column with no extra properties.

For example:

```
<columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
</columnConstraints>
<rowConstraints> 
    <RowConstriants />
</rowContraints>
```

Comment: I know it already. I'm asking why SceneBuilder generate this useless code if I work with GridPane?

Comment: It doesn't hurt anything. They probably just have a loop that prints all the column constraints and put the tags there regardless. That way if there's changes it doesn't miss them